# How could i set the popup size to it's content?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Popup control in WPF that loades it's content dynamically and each time I need to set it's size, how could this be automatically done, so it allways keeps it's size to it's content size.

```
<Popup 
      Name="popup1" 
      StaysOpen="False" 
      PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=myButton}" 
      Placement="Custom" 
      PopupAnimation="Fade" 
      AllowsTransparency="True">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx) already sizes according to content.

> **By default, a Popup is automatically sized to its content.** When
>   auto-sizing occurs, some bitmap effects may be hidden because the
>   default size of the screen area that is defined for the Popup content
>   does not provide enough space for the bitmap effects to display.
>
> Popup content can also be obscured when you set a RenderTransform on
>   the content. In this scenario, some content might be hidden if the
>   content of the transformed Popup extends beyond the area of the
>   original Popup. If a bitmap effect or transform requires more space,
>   you can define a margin around the Popup content in order to provide
>   more area for the control.

Perhaps your `Popup` content is having sizing issues due to you restricting growth within your layout container? Your Popup is thus sized accordingly but your `Grid` for example may have a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a long time back. I want to say it's because the popup is not part of the visual tree and therefor you don't have access to re-render it based on the dynamic contents. What I did was to create a child control that looked like a popup but was part of the visual tree and everything worked as expected.

This is just a foggy old memory but it could be a good jumping point for searching for a more concrete answer.

Comment: You can never create a window that is part of the visual tree.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking just a child control with a masked overlay to gray out the screen around the new control which is absolutely positioned in order to make it appear to be a popup but it's still just a UserControl and thus part of the visual tree?

Comment: UserControls are always in some visual tree, but windows cannot be the visual child of anything.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect this. I really just wasn't being very specific and was trying to convey a concept. Thanks for helping to clear up my memory a bit!